# Make all elements unique in a dataframe

Tags: r

Assuming I have data looks like below.

At this entire data, in total I have 3*A, 2*B, 2*C, and only 1 D, E, and F.

```
data <- read.table(textConnection("
col1 col2 
A B
A C
B A
C D
E F
"), header = TRUE)
```

What I want to do is to keep the order and contents the same, BUT make them unique.
For example, the A becomes A.1, A.2, and A.3.

```
col1 col2 
A.1 B.2
A.2 C.2
B.1 A.3
C.1 D
E F
```

Is there any smart way I can do this?

I know I can use `make.unique` or `make.names`, but it looks like it only can work for one column, not for entire dataset.

Comment: `dat[] <- lapply(dat, make.unique)`?

Comment: @Jaap Anywhere wrong? http://imgur.com/a/wuisa

Comment: `as.character()` should be called inside `make.unique`: `as.data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) make.unique(as.character(x))))`

Comment: @Daniel  any missing? http://imgur.com/JHR2QOJ

Comment: Do you want them sequentially numbered, or being unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `unlist` the dataset, then use `ave` to get the sequence, `paste` with the unlisted vector and assign it back to the original dataset

```
v1 <- as.character(unlist(data))
data[] <- sub("\\.$", "", paste(v1, ave(v1, v1,
         FUN = function(x) if(length(x)>1) seq_along(x) else ""), sep="."))
data
#  col1 col2
#1  A.1  B.2
#2  A.2  C.2
#3  B.1  A.3
#4  C.1    D
#5    E    F
```

Answer (score 5):

Using:

```
dat[] <- make.unique(as.character(unlist(dat)))
```

gives:

> ```
> > dat
>   col1 col2
> 1    A  B.1
> 2  A.1  C.1
> 3    B  A.2
> 4    C    D
> 5    E    F
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The OP requires that the values in the data.frame should be made *unique across all columns*. This is a strong indicator that the data better should be *reshaped from wide to long format* where all data manipulations can be performed on *one* column instead of many.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(data)
molten <- melt(DT, measure.vars = names(DT))[
  , value := paste(value, rowid(value), sep = ".")]
molten
```

> ```
>     variable value
>  1:     col1   A.1
>  2:     col1   A.2
>  3:     col1   B.1
>  4:     col1   C.1
>  5:     col1   E.1
>  6:     col2   B.2
>  7:     col2   C.2
>  8:     col2   A.3
>  9:     col2   D.1
> 10:     col2   F.1
> ```

The `rowid()` function is a convenience function for generating a unique row id within each group.

Further processing can continue in the long format. Finally, the data may be reshaped to wide format again:

```
molten[, rn := rowid(variable)][, dcast(.SD, rn ~ variable)][, rn := NULL][]
```

> ```
>    col1 col2
> 1:  A.1  B.2
> 2:  A.2  C.2
> 3:  B.1  A.3
> 4:  C.1  D.1
> 5:  E.1  F.1
> ```

[Jaap's `make.unique()` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45053022/3817004)  can be used as well:

```
melt(DT, measure.vars = names(DT))[, value := make.unique(value)][]
```

> ```
>     variable value
>  1:     col1     A
>  2:     col1   A.1
>  3:     col1     B
>  4:     col1     C
>  5:     col1     E
>  6:     col2   B.1
>  7:     col2   C.1
>  8:     col2   A.2
>  9:     col2     D
> 10:     col2     F
> ```